# There is already an object named 'STUD1' in the database

Tags: sql-server, database

This is my query which I try to run on my database but I found these 3 errors below keep happened.

```
CREATE VIEW STUD1 
AS
    SELECT 
        *, 
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY R.ContractID 
                                ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, LEFT(EVAL_PERIOD , charindex('-', EVAL_PERIOD) - 1), 103) DESC)
    FROM 
        SCMD3.DBO.CPE R;
GO

CREATE VIEW STUD2 
AS
     SELECT 
         C.ContractID,
         GRED1 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN ALL_GRADE END),
         MARK1 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN ALL_SCORE END),
         GRED2 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN ALL_GRADE END),
         MARK2 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN ALL_SCORE END)
     FROM  
         STUD1 C
     GROUP BY 
         C.ContractID;
GO

SELECT 
    s.ContractTitle, x.GRED1, x.MARK1, x.GRED2, x.MARK2 
FROM 
    STUD2 x 
INNER JOIN 
    SCMD3.DBO.CONTRACTMASTER s ON x.ContractID = s.ID;
```

I get errors:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Procedure STUD1, Line 2
> There is already an object named 'STUD1' in the database.
>
> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Procedure STUD2, Line 9
> There is already an object named 'STUD2' in the database.
>
> Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 20
> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

I have tried a few solutions but still failed to execute. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first two error are saying the views are already in database. the 3rd one says invalid parameter, maybe EVAL_PRIOD is no a varvhar (string) type

Comment: If you keep executing the whole script, it's going to try to create the views each time. If those CREATE VIEW statements already succeeded, then running them again will generate the errors you are getting.

Comment: @FLICKER  I keep changing the view name but still got same error..and data type for EVAL_PERIOD is varchar(250)

Comment: @siride owh..I really forgot about that. View is different from other then left about invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function for  the error

Comment: if you want use this repeatedly, then shouldnt use "CREATE VIEW"

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you already have an object with that name. You can see what what object it is finding by running the following script.

```
USE MyDatabaseName
GO

SELECT * 
FROM sys.all_objects 
WHERE NAME = 'STUD1'
```

If it helps track it down, you can use

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(1678629023)
```

to view the SQL that creates that object.